# imap_mail_copy isn't copiing emails to desired folder - php

Tags: php, email, copy, imap, move

i'm trying to do the following: read a mailbox (domain mailbox), then read the emails, do whatever depending on subject and body and finaly copy the email to a folder named **done**.

The problem is that

```
imap_mail_copy($mailbox, $messageIDs, 'INBOX.done', CP_UID);
```

is not working. (i tried with imap_mail_move, but it deletes my email without copiing it first, as this is annoying i'm working with copy till i find the solution).

i'm reading well the emails so i can echo date, subject, fromaddress, body utf8 formatted and quoted printable decoded. I'm stuck in that last step...
I tried like everything on php official webpage, reading doc and try-error the examples.

I tried using $messageIDs as some msg id separated by commas (without spaces) like 1,3,4. I tried with 1 harcoded and with 1 dinamically. The result is the same... nothing.
Anny suggestion?

Comment: may i have to search by some internal hidden name or ID of mailbox folders to use this name or id instead 'INBOX.done' ?
if yes, how can i accomplish it? thanks

Comment: Depends on how your server organizes the folders.  You may want to print out the output of a LIST command.

Comment: i've a folder into inbox folder, named **done** , so i'm trying to use 'INBOX.done' or 'done' but it does not work.

Comment: It might be INBOX/Done or otherwise, that's why you should run a LIST to see what it's real name is.

Comment: i ran a list and get mailboxes. It's INBOX/done, but i've just tried with "INBOX/done", "INBOX.done", "done" and "/INBOX/done/" and nothing happened anyway.
i get this result referred to the folder i want to use:

**(3) {mail.domain.com}INBOX/done,'/',64** I dont know how to deal with, i've read like hundred forums and still get stuck.

Comment: if i'm not understanding wrong, **(3)** is the folder key, **"{mail.domain.com}INBOX/done"** this is the imap_utf7_decoded name, this **'/'** is the delimiter, and **64** is the attribute (64 = has no children, 32 = has children folders). so i've tried to use the key to copy message on it but has no effect.